# How can I uninstall a language?

Tags: wp-admin, language

I changed my site language a few times for testing purposes. The problem is that after changing it back, WordPress continues to update plugin language packs. How can I uninstall those languages that got installed when I selected them as the Site Language for testing? If I select the Site Language dropdown, I can still see them under "Installed".

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hope you have FTP access or some alike, so you can follow path as shown below.

Use any FTP tool (FileZilla or some) and enter your website.

1) Go to the `wp-content` folder
There you will see a folder named `languages`.

2) Go into the `languages` folder
There you will find a folder called `plugins` and `themes`.

3) Enter the `plugins` folder
You will see files which probably will end with `-es_ES.mo and -es_ES.po` which is for Español and maybe also `-es_CO.mo and -es_CO.po` which is for Español de Colombia.
All files as named above in this folder you can delete without any problem.

4) Enter the `themes` folder (if you wish to do it also for the theme translations)
Follow step 3. (the deleting part)

> Edit:
>   Ofcourse are there also translation files for WordPress core itself in the `wp-content/languages` folder, these `-es_ES and -es_CO` files you can also delete ofcourse.

Now you are done but remember they (or other) will be back when you switch the language again in the admin (Settings/General) and let WordPress update the translation(s) or doing it yourself by selecting to update all.

Hope this helped you out.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. If I don't change the Site Language, then will WordPress still re-download all those translation files?

Answer (score 6):

In order to reset to English only?
You will have to remove all files in these folders:

```
/wp-content/languages
/wp-content/languages/plugins
/wp-content/languages/themes
```

Remember that your default language will be used. If you installed a wrong version the language might be still present. So you will have to overwrite your files with new installation zip or tar.gz file from Wordpress on English. If that is applicable.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, there is a much simpler way:

go to Settings > Languages and disable all the languages you don't want to be present nor used on your wesite.

Answer (score -3):

There is quickest way to reset to English or any other language. Go to WP-Admin from your blog home page. Select Settings and choose GENERAL from menus and under this General settings page, down below near "Save Changes" blue button, you will see language box, where you can change to English or something else. Save Changes and you are done.

Comment: That is not the problem in the question.

Comment: The question is how to remove a language pack from the site, so this doesn't actually address the question.  Changing the language does not remove the installed language pack.