# Why translations?

Tags: translation

I wonder why my WordPress installation has frequent updates for all sorts of translations, as my webpage is in a single language only (German). Is there some way to uninstall languages/translations that are not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you will need at least translations into german.

there shouldn't be other packages loaded for your site.
you can find these files in the `language` folders in `wp-content`.
there are other `language` folders as well in the plugins or in thmemes.

Comment: To expand: for some time now plugins and themes usually don't ship their own translations, but use them via GlotPress (eg [here is the link to YOAST](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/wordpress-seo)). So when translations of a plugin are updated, you do this via regular "updates" and not by updating the plugin itself.

Comment: Can I remove languages that I think I do not need? If yes, how? (Probably just deleting them in "wp-content/languages/" is not a good option.) Or is it better to keep them all?

Comment: @BodoManthey "wordpress remove language" found me answers [like this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/262600/how-can-i-uninstall-a-language).

Comment: @BodoManthey You can control translation updates with WordPress hooks while still allowing code updates. [This example](https://gist.github.com/timwhitlock/8d4d2fa35c0ab312d040223ef6990e5b) uses [this hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/auto_update_type/)