# Admin keeps showing pending translation update

Tags: updates, translation, warnings

1. WP shows that I have a pending update
2. In `/wp-admin/update-core.php`, I see it's a translation update
3. I press the update translation button
4. The update warning disappears
5. ... and after a few moments of use, the update translation warning appears again

And as much as I repeat all the steps again, the warning always comes back.
What can be done?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved following https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/262613/143330.
Deleting unused language files inside /wp-content.